Query @azure/openai with images?
On chat.openai.com I can upload an image and ask chatgpt a question about it, with the existing openai and @azure/openai api however there doesn't seem to be a way to do this? The ChatCompletion object in both cases only take text prompts.
Is this feautre supported at an api level?

With OpenAI you just include your image as part of the message that you supply. Here is a piece from the code I use, which works whether you have an image or not:
if image != '':
    # Get base64 string
    base64_image = encode_image(image)
    content = [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": your_prompt
        },
        {
            "type": "image_url",
            "image_url": {
                "url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_image}"
            }
        }
    ]
else:
    content = your_prompt
messages.append({"role": "user", "content": content})

And then
payload = {
    "model": model_name,
    "temperature": temperature,
    "max_tokens": tokens,
    "messages": messages
}

where encode_image() is defined:
def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

Currently you need to target OpenAI model gpt-4-vision-preview. Update: As  @Michael suggests, it also works with gpt-4o.

Thanks for the help! Curious can it just be a remote url or does it have to be a base64 embedded image?

Glad to help. Yes you can use the URL to an image online with "url": "https: . . . "

This implementation also works perfectly with GPT-4o.

@meds - I'm just wondering - since the accepted answer just deals with openai (not Azure) it would probably be useful to change the question title to: 'Query openai with images?' (no need to change the body of the question). That way people searching for an Azure fix will not waste time, while for those wanting an openai fix it will be a more obvious place to go.
